# Multiple Wordpress instances vs Multisite (performance-wise)

Tags: wordpress

I have around 15 Wordpress sites, all of them are very low traffic (100-500 reqs/day) and I want to host these on a small VPS (actually, a Linode 512), serving these with the Nginx/php-fpm combo.
The question is the following: will 15 wordpress installs use more RAM than a single multisite install ?

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread, the performance difference is negligible: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/performance-of-wpmu-vs-single-installs

However, the time you save on administrative tasks might make Multisite worth the effort (WordPress updates, theme & plugin updates, backups, etc).

Comment: Thx Chris; the link helped. In fact, I want to migrate from multisite to multiple instances because of bad plugin interraction issues I experienced. One last question though: since I'm using php-fpm, do I need to set one pool per site/host, or can I use one pool to serve all sites ? Because multiple php-fpm pools will cause higher memory consumption.